# How to insert SCTE-35 markers in Livestream/Playout

Tags: ads, http-live-streaming, ott, scte-35

AWS media convert support SCTE-35 markers insertion for VOD content only, which further detected by media tailor and replace the ads from given ad server in realtime.

Is their any tool or package that I can use to insert SCTE-35 markers to livestream/playout feeds. For detection I am going to use aws media tailor.

I have searched across the internet but did not found a feasible solution.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Live feed example: https://vidcdn.vidgyor.com/news24-origin/liveabr/playlist.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

AWS Media Convert is designed for VOD use cases - the Live equivalent is AWS Media Live.

AWS Media Live does support insertion of SCTE-35 markers using its scheduling functionality:

> The schedule is a list of actions that a channel performs as it is running. You can use actions to do the following:
>
> [other options also but removed here for simplicity]
>
> Insert SCTE-35 messages into the running channel.

The documentation is available online: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/sched-how-actions-work.html

Other vendor's encoders provide similar functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

[**SuperKabuki**](https://github.com/futzu/SuperKabuki) does SCTE-35 packet injection on live mpegts streams.

[**x9k3**](https://github.com/futzu/x9k3) does SCTE-35 insertion for live HLS.